# Accessing lunching event information in callback for inline buttons

Tags: python-telegram-bot

My bot use inline buttons, so I use [CallbackQueryHandler](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.8.1/telegram.ext.callbackqueryhandler.html).

I need to get a string of command that launched callback, one I would get from `update.message.text` if I would use [MessageHandler](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.8.1/telegram.ext.messagehandler.html), as in [conversation2.py](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/v13.8.1/examples/conversationbot2.py) example.

What is a way to get same information for inline buttons?

Answer (score 0):

In function called by `CallbackQueryHandler` we should use next code:

```
query = update.callback_query
query.answer()
logging.warning(f"query.data is {query.data}")
```

Defines passed to `CallbackQueryHandler` `pattern` parameter should be defined as `range` not `map(str,range..)`